# symfony 3.4 phpunit and fixtures

Tags: symfony, phpunit, fixtures

I want to create some fixtures for different environnement, for example prod to load default values, dev for the developpers and test for testing with phpunit.

I have create an abstract class

```
    abstract class AbstractFixture extends Fixture implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    protected $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null): void
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        $kernel = $this->container->get('kernel');
        if (\in_array($kernel->getEnvironment(), $this->getEnvironments(), true)) {
            $this->doLoad($manager);
        }
    }

    abstract protected function getEnvironments();

    abstract protected function doLoad(ObjectManager $manager);
}
```

For example if i want a fixture for dev environnement

```
    class DevFixture extends AbstractFixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    public function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [
            AppFixture::class,
            DevFixture::class,
        ];
    }

    protected function getEnvironments(): array
    {
        return ['dev'];
    }

    protected function doLoad(ObjectManager $objectManager): void
    {
    }
}
```

When I run bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env dev 
it's ok

Now I want to use this fixture for testing my app with phpunit.
I want for each test the fixture is loaded.

I want to know how can do this ? using setUp() and running the doctrine:fixtures:load --env dev command or there is an other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to achieve the behaviour you are expecting , I think you can use the `bootstrap.php` that will be run once before all your tests.

A sample for what I am trying to say:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

echo 'Recreating and Seeding Database';
passthru('php "'.__DIR__.'/../bin/console" doctrine:database:drop --force --env=test');
passthru('php "'.__DIR__.'/../bin/console" doctrine:database:create --env=test');
passthru('php "'.__DIR__.'/../bin/console" doctrine:schema:create --env=test');
passthru('php "'.__DIR__.'/../../bin/console" doctrine:fixtures:load --env=test');
echo ' Done'.PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: I have use a complemetary bundle dama/doctrine-test-bundle, this bundle use Transaction to undo database modification. I have explain on my deleted post :(